# Unity - Get ID from OneSignal

Tags: unity-game-engine, onesignal

What is the correct way to get the Onesignal user ID?

```
OSPermissionSubscriptionState state = OneSignal.GetPermissionSubscriptionState();
extraMessage = " UserId: "+state.subscriptionStatus.userId;
```

This method seams strange to me, because there is no event dispatched when the ID arrives. How can I be sure that the app already has the ID?

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

```
OneSignal.subscriptionObserver += OneSignal_subscriptionObserver;

private void OneSignal_subscriptionObserver(OSSubscriptionStateChanges stateChanges)
{
    extraMessage = "OneSignal_subscriptionObserver UserId: " + stateChanges.to.userId;
}
```